# wp_query order by a date meta value on woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i'm using woocommerce to sell newspaper so i added custom field to store release dates. I wanted to show products sorted by their release date. I used the following code:

```
$args = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_related_products_args', array(
'post_type'            => 'product',
'ignore_sticky_posts'  => 1,
'no_found_rows'        => 1,
'posts_per_page'       => $posts_per_page,
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'wccaf_de',
        'value'   => $name,
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ),
),
'meta_key'   => 'wccaf_release_date',
'meta_type'  => 'DATE',
'orderby'    => 'meta_value_date',
'order'      => 'ASC',
'post__not_in'         => array( $product->id )
) );
$products = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I tried also to use a add_filter as i've seen on https://konstantin.blog/2012/order-by-post-meta-casted-date-wp_query/
but it didn't work. For me, i think that the problem is

1. on the stored value which is not a date but a string
2. even if the cast on the add_filter was successful i'm not sure about the sorting function

   Somebody have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify some parameters to the meta_query as explain [Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters). I don't find `meta_type` parameter except for the `order_by` value. You can define the `meta_key` type in the `meta_query` array,

> type (string) - Custom field type. Possible values are 'NUMERIC', 'BINARY', 'CHAR', 'DATE', 'DATETIME', 'DECIMAL', 'SIGNED', 'TIME', 'UNSIGNED'. Default value is 'CHAR'.
>
> The 'type' DATE works with the 'compare' value BETWEEN only if the
>   date is stored at the format YYYY-MM-DD and tested with this format.

```
$args = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_related_products_args', array(
     'post_type'            => 'product',
     'ignore_sticky_posts'  => 1,
     'no_found_rows'        => 1,
     'posts_per_page'       => $posts_per_page,
     'meta_query' => array(
           array(
              'key'     => 'wccaf_release_date',
              'value'   => $name,
              'compare' => 'LIKE',
              'type'    => 'DATE'
          ),
     ),
     'meta_key'   => 'wccaf_release_date',         
     'orderby'    => array('meta_type'=> 'DATE'),
     'order'      => 'ASC',
     'post__not_in'         => array( $product->id )
    ) 
);
```

Be careful your meta_key name is not the same and I think it needs to.

Hope it gives you some hints !